# Inject service or unit test Validation attribute ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I inject a service into my custom validation attribute? If that is not possible the alternative is to setup the `ValidationContext` to resolve that services in my tests.

How can I achieve one of these ?

```
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dateOfBirth = (DateTime)value;

        var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var minimumAge = new DateTime(currentDate.Year - 17, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, currentDate.Hour, currentDate.Minute, currentDate.Second);
        var maximumAge = new DateTime(currentDate.Year - 34, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, currentDate.Hour, currentDate.Minute, currentDate.Second);

        var isTooYoung = dateOfBirth > minimumAge;
        var isTooOld = dateOfBirth < maximumAge;

        if (isTooYoung || isTooOld) 
        {
            // it is about this line
            var localizer = (ILocalizer)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ILocalizer));
            var error = localizer.GetString(ErrorMessageString);
            return new ValidationResult(error);
        } 

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this artical, it tells you how to inject services & data into validation attributes:

https://rossjayjones.github.io/dotnetcore/aspnetcore/mvc/dotnet/2018/09/09/injecting-services-into-validation-attributes-aspnetcore.html